# need to find sum of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k+1)}$

Tags: summation

need to find sum of

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k+1)}$$

this is much harder as I see.
Or maybe it's my eyes, because I'm new in studying sums.

I tried this one using differences , factorial  powers, didn't help.

Comment: It is telescopic. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Note that $\frac{2^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{2^k}{k}=\frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k+1)}$

Comment: Try to write linear term as partial sum, rest will follow.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get a telescoping series as follows, $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(\color{red}2k-(k+1))2^k}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k\color{red}{+1}}}{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{2^1}{1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Simple telescopic series
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k + 1)} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \bigg( \frac{2^{k + 1}}{k + 1} - \frac{2^{k}}{k} \bigg) = \frac{2^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - {2} $$